# Internal Server Error 500 en Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, mod-rewrite

Tengo una web alojada en Digital Ocean que corre en un Ubuntu bajo Lamp con PHP & MySQL. Mi problema recide a que cuando quiero pasar datos por APIRest me da un error interno.

Este es mi codigo

```
function ajaxPost(url, encodedata, success)
{
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:url,
data :encodedata,
dataType:"json",
contentType: 'application/json',
cache:false,
timeout:50000,
beforeSend :function(data) 
{ 
$(".scrollMore").attr("rel","0"); 
$("#networkError").slideUp("slow"); 
},
success:function(data){

success.call(this, data);
$(".scrollMore").attr("rel","1"); 
},
error:function(data){
$("#networkError").show().html($.networkError);
}
});
}
```

Primero pense que el error era en el mod_Rewrite pero sospecho que debe estar aquí. Sinceramente ya me estoy rindiendo. Probe en local trabajando bajo un entorno Windows y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Un error 500 es disparado por el servidor, no por el cliente. Por lo tanto, o el error está en el .htaccess, o en el código de tu API.... y si puede ser el .htaccess, deberías agregarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Si el cliente hace mal una llamada, el servidor debería responder con un 400 (bad request), un 500 es, como bien dice su nombre, un problema del servidor